# PHP code to separate Table based on column values

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that should be converted to HTML table based on column values , and I have to put the values into separate table based on first column of csv . And I think the problem is because of '\n' in first column.

So its like this:

[image: csv Image]

Here in `Result` column, in one row I have three values separated using comma (W,M,P). In the code I wrote it is considered as separate table headers .
Can anyone please help me with this?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    $csv="FinalResult.csv" ;
    $csvcontents=file_get_contents($csv);
    $csv_array = explode("\n", $csvcontents);
    
    $tables = [];
    foreach($csv_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        $line = explode(',', $value);
        if (array_key_exists($line[0], $tables)) {
            $tables[$line[0]][] = $line;
        } else {
            $tables[$line[0]] = [$line];
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
        echo '<h1> ' .$key. ' </h1>'; // YOUR TITLE (Team)
        echo "<table>";
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach (explode(',', $csv_array[0]) as $keyHeader => $valueHeader) {
            if (in_array($keyHeader, [0, 1])) {
                continue;
            }
            echo "<th>$valueHeader</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        foreach ($value as $keyRow => $valueRow) {
            echo '<tr>';
                foreach ($valueRow as $keyValue => $valueValue) {
                    if (in_array($keyValue, [0, 1])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    echo "<td>$valueValue</td>";
                }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```

I refereed in stack overflow , but there they were giving only single values to a column and not providing multiple values .

But am getting output like this ,
[image: Output]

so it takes the value of Result column after '-' as a new heading , i tried but am not able to solve this , can anyone really help me in this matter .

Here is how my output should look like:

[image: how my output should look like]

I marked in yellow where all the data am getting in same column

This is my csv file :

```
Team,Date,Opponent,Result
    MIN,May-03,UTA,a.b.c=d-e.f-g.h=log4j2-i.xml-j -k -a4j.k=tp_r-RR.xml -
    MIN,May-04,SEA,"L,Q,J"
    SAC,May-03,DAL,L
    SAC,May-04,TOR,W
    NYN,May-05,BAL,L
    NYN,May-07,MIA,W
```

Comment: i just edited the code

Comment: so i will show my desired output in code @Chilarai

Comment: so i just edited code and gave the problem clearly @Chilarai , the thing is it it taking the value of column after edit has a new header . Can you help me in this

Comment: sorry , i checked it and got to know , its not based on comma , but based on  '\n' in column . @Chilarai

Comment: **Paste your csv file here.**  And also, **should the HTML table look exactly like the CSV?**

Comment: yeah , my csv file and how it should look like is given in my question @Chilarai

Comment: It is difficult to try the code without your csv file. I cannot go and type each and every word in csv. So please paste the csv file in the question

Comment: ok sure i will give u my csv file

Comment: yeah done , i gave it in question . now you can directly copy paste that @Chilarai

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
<table>
<?php 
    $csvValues=  array_map('str_getcsv', file('FinalResult.csv'));
    $counter = 0;

    // Header
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($csvValues[0] as $headers){
        echo "<th>".$headers."</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    // Content
    foreach($csvValues as $values){
        echo "<tr>";

        if($counter >0){
            foreach($values as $data){
                echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
            }
        }   
        
        echo "</tr>";
        $counter++; 
    }

?>
</table>
```